# How to figure out if my Windows installation is a fresh install or not?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

A couple of months ago I've reinstalled windows but it hasn't been working very well. I forgot whether I fresh installed or used Reset PC option. Is there any way to figure out if my windows installation is new or did I use Reset PC?

Comment: Which version of Windows is in question?

Comment: Windows 10. Install date is 2/1/2016 which coincides with the time when I reinstalled or resetted windows.

Comment: When you perform a Reset windows is reinstalled.  There is no difference between a "clean install" and using the Reset feature within Windows and selecting to keep nothing.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I just noticed something strange though. I was checking regedit and noticed my old user profile in HKEY_USERS from my previous Windows install. If I indeed made a clean install or performed a reset how is this possible that my windows profile from one year ago is still there although not in use?

Comment: Then i guess you have your answer, you didn't do a clean install, you only did a reset of sorts (i don't know what 'reset' does w10 have)